# To get all the lines from the log except the lines with particular string

Tags: shell, unix, aix

The following code gives output of a log containing the string "Type: Error"

```
grep -E "$Currentdate" *.log |  grep "Type: Error" | sort -u
```

what is the code If I want to get output of all the lines in log except the lines with string "Type: Error"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat logFile | grep -v "Type: Error"
```

With this, first, you'll display to video your file, then you'll use `-v` option that invert the matches and the trick is done!

For multiple string, you could do something like this

```
cat logFile | egrep -v '(firstString)|(secondString)|(thirdString)|...|(nString)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-v` option grep that will do the trick.

Comment: what if I want to exclude multiple stings?

Comment: Choose a right pattern to exclude. use `|` for matching multiple strings. You need to escape `|` for basic regex.